Deserialize String from API in FlutterFlow
I am working with an API which returns me a json that is below, it turns out that this json brings a data that arrives in string format that brings important information for the app.
The problem is that I have not been able to deserialize said String in flutterflow, I tried with a custom action that receives a string and with json.decode it deserializes it but returns a map <>, but I don't know how to take that map to a listView that I have in the screen mounted with flutterflow.
I would like you to please guide me a little on this topic since it is limiting my progress and everything that GPT has suggested has not worked for me.
Json:
{
"codigo": 1,
"mensaje": null,
"data": [{"anhos_id":1.0,"anhos_fecha":"2024-10-02T00:00:00","anhos_valor":1000000.0,"anhos_viaje_id":22.0},{"anhos_id":3.0,"anhos_fecha":"2024-10-08T00:00:00","anhos_valor":1000000.0,"anhos_viaje_id":21.0}]
}

at the end you want data = [["anhos_id":1.0,"anhos_fecha":"2024-10-02T00:00:00","anhos_valor":1000000.0,"anhos_viaje_id":22.0],["anhos_id":3.0,"anhos_fecha":"2024-10-08T00:00:00","anhos_valor":1000000.0,"anhos_viaje_id":21.0]]
and want to access data[0][0] like this is my understanding is right
